# How do I get _url working with reverse proxy? Specifically NGinX with Passenger Standalone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have an environment setup w/ nginx+passenger standalone.  I'm just using nginx as a reverse proxy.  My issue is that if I'm running the site on port 3333, If I use a _url instead of _path like projects_url instead of projects_path, the url comes out like http://99.99.99.99:3333/projects.

How do I get those working correctly and just use the domain?  Is there a setting in rails?

I'm using rails 2.3.8 for this particular project and the gem I'm using is using _url everywhere so it would be quite a pain to change all of those to _path.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself.  I switched to using a unix socket instead of a tcp/ip port.